# Can you host multiple apps under the same hostname/origin?

Tags: web-hosting, amazon-aws, next.js

I am building multiple apps (hosted on separate AWS amplify instances) using Next.js and I would like to host these apps under the same origin ([www.example.com/app1](http://www.example.com/app1), [www.example.com/app2](http://www.example.com/app2)). I don't want to use different domain prefixes, ie. app1.example.com, because it makes the apps feel like completely different things.

Comment: In my opinion, subdomains don't make apps feel completely different. There are other factors which have a much bigger impact:  1) The look and feel 2) Information architecture (how well they interlink)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting these apps behind a single reverse proxy server or CDN - ie have a webserver that answers all requests and then pulls requests from the appropriate backend depending on URL.

Comment: Specifically, if you are on AWS, you should look into using [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) which is the AWS CDN that integrates nicely with the rest of the AWS ecosystem and supports the path routing features that are needed.